# How can i create or update one entity on another was created

Tags: javascript, mysql, typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I would appreciate your help

I have several tables in my database: stores, sales and stocks and i want to update stock when i save new sale in my sales table.

There are my entities
sale

```
@Entity()
export class Sale {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @ManyToOne((type) => Store, (store) => store.sales)
  store: Store

  @Column()
  productId: number

  @Column()
  user: number

  @Column()
  count: number

  @Column()
  sum: number

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createDate: Date
}
```

stock

```
@Entity()
export class Stock {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @Column()
  product: number

  @ManyToOne((type) => Store, (store) => store.stocks)
  store: Store

  @Column()
  count: number
}
```

the stock entity contains the product id and the store id,
the sale entity also contains these properties. What i want?
Well, when i save in the db new sale, i want to find item in the stock table where stock.product = sale.product and the stock.store = sale.store, and then update its count field like this stock.count = stock.count + sale count. Is this possible?

I can use the stock service inside the sale service and implement this logic, but i thought there will be a much clean method...

Answer (score 0):

use cascade to save, update, and delete in both sides each time you do an action to your sale Entity
note => cascade work only on one side => Sale Side

```
@Entity()
export class Sale {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number

  @ManyToOne((type) => Store, (store) => store.sales , {cascade : true})
  store: Store

  @Column()
  productId: number

  @Column()
  user: number

  @Column()
  count: number

  @Column()
  sum: number

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createDate: Date
}
```